# Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to add a `WHERE` clause to my SQL statement but get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

when running the program.

My SQL statement

```
insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [UserInformation]  (Password, NewUser) " _
            & "Values('" & Pw1 & "', '" & NewUSR & "') WHERE ([Email] = '" & txtUserName2 & "') "
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: makes no sense to have where in insert statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the meaning of a WHERE clause in a [INSERT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)?
You should remove everything after the closing parenthesys for the values

Of course, you should also not use string concatenation in sql statements because your code is exposed to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

```
 insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [UserInformation]  " & _
                             "(Password, NewUser) Values(@pwd,@newusr)" 
 insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Pw1)
 insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", NewUSR )
```

Instead, if your plan is to UPDATE the record, then the WHERE is required, but the query text is different

```
 updateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [UserInformation]  " & _
                             "SET Password = @pwd, NewUser = @newusr " & _
                             "WHERE ([Email] = @email) "
```

If you use parameters to pass your values you remove the possibility of SQL Injection, but another great benefit is that now your query text is not littered with open/close quotes. You leave the correct parsing of your command (including the exact resolution of the parameters) to the underlying database code.

Comment: Thanks as soon as you said " What is the meaning of a WHERE clause in a INSERT statement? " I realised I need the UPDATE statement and yours works great!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to so an INSERT and SELECT combo.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx